# How to retrieve MongoDB multiple array values in php?

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to retrieve all the values of the field **color**. How do php handle this values?

```
{
    _id : 1,

    color : ["red","blue","yellow"]
},
{
    _id : 2,

    color : ["green","black","grey"]
}
```

**PHP code :**

```
<?php

    $connect = new MongoClient();

    $collection = $database->database_name->collection;

    $cursor = $collection->find( array(), array( 'color' ) );

    foreach( $cursor as $val )

     echo json_encode( $val );

?>
```

As a result it does not return any values. How do I get the array values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [distinct](http://php.net/manual/fr/mongocollection.distinct.php) to get distinct values of your array :

```
$cursor = $collection->distinct('color');
```

A full example :

```
<?php

    $m = new MongoClient();
    $db = $m->selectDB("testDB");
    $cursor = $db->users->distinct('color');
    var_dump($cursor);

?>
```

Comment: the values are returned as a single value, I want the values to be returned as an array.

Comment: Do you mean like `["red","blue","yellow"],["green","black","grey"]` ?

Comment: Ok! got it, resolved. Your code worked. Ignore the previous comment. Thanks.